Strange behavior of Subdivide
I run into some weird thing related to the function Subdivide. See the following example:
x = Subdivide[0,0.2,10];
y = Range[0,0.2,0.02];
x == y
MemberQ[x,0.06]
MemberQ[y,0.06]

The output is
True
False
True

Am I missing something?
I'm using Mathematica 14.0 in Linux.

Subdivide  achieves the result as FullForm[0 + 3*0.2/10] which is 0.06000000000000001 while Range as FullForm[0 + 3*0.02] which is 0.06. So they use slightly different steps which can be seen on full-form of 0.2/10 and 0.02 that they are not exactly same.

Related but a side issue, perhaps: MemberQ[x, #] & /@ y and PossibleZeroQ[x - y] return different True/False lists.

Thanks for the comments and answers. I realize that this may be caused by a misunderstanding from my part about how comparisons are made, so feel free to close it if you feel it doesn't belong here.
The fact that Position[Subdivide[0, 0.2, 10], 0.06] returned an empty list seemed bizarre to me.

If Position[Subdivide[0, 0.2, 10], 0.06] is something you need to do with approximate floating-point numbers, try Position[Subdivide[0, 0.2, 10], x_ /; x == 0.06]. Or the standard Position[Subdivide[0, 0.2, 10], x_ /; Abs[x - 0.06] < 10^-12] with whatever tolerance instead of 10^-12 you wish.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

(x = Subdivide[0, 0.2, 10]) // InputForm

(* {0., 0.020000000000000004, 
0.04000000000000001, 
0.06000000000000001, 
0.08000000000000002, 0.1, 
0.12000000000000002, 0.14, 
0.16000000000000003, 
0.18000000000000002, 0.2} *)

0.06 // InputForm

(* 0.06 *)

MemberQ[x, 0.06]

(* False *)

From  the  documentation  for  MemberQ, "MemberQ[list, form] returns True if an element of list matches form, and False otherwise."
(y = Range[0, 0.2, 0.02]) // InputForm

(* {0., 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 
0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2} *)

MemberQ[y, 0.06]

(* True *)

x == y

(* True *)

From the documentation for Equal, "Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)."
Compare with SameQ
x === y

(* False *)

EDIT: Using higher precision in the Subdivide
(x = Subdivide[0, 0.2`15, 10] // N) // InputForm

(* {0., 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 
 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2} *)

MemberQ[x, 0.06]

(* True *)

